# Problema por string inmutable....python

Tags: python

Buenas , estoy realizando un código y me he encontrado con un problema por la inmutabilidad de un string y no poder evitarlo.Bien pongo el código y explico:

```
 def muevecoche(letramov,nveles,guarda):
     elemento = nvles[guarda]
     for poyito in range(0,len(elemento)): # Extrae los valores del string.
         cadena = elemento [poyito]
         orientacion = cadena [0]
         corx = cadena[1] 
         corx = int(corx) ; corx = corx*3-2 # Establece en una celda de la matriz 3x3 la pos x
         cory = cadena[2]
         cory= int(cory); cory = cory*3-2 # Establece en una celda de la matriz 3x3 la pos y
         longitud = cadena[3]
         longitud = int(longitud)
         longitud = longitud *3 #  Multiplicacion x 3 , casillas de long 3.

     if orientacion == 'H': # Movimiento en posición horizontal.
         anchura = corx + longitud
        altura = cory+3
        for j in range(cory,altura): # Limpio la posicion anterior.
            for h in range(corx,anchura):
                t[j][h] = ' '
        if letramov <= ord('Z'): # Movimiento recibido hacia izq...
            corx= corx-3
            cadena[1] = str(corx)
            anchura = anchura-3
        elif letramov >= ord('a'): # Movimiento hacia la derecha
            corx=corx+3     
            cadena[1] = str(corx)
            anchura = anchura+3
       for j in range(cory,altura): # Pinto dicho coche
           for h in range(corx,anchura):
              t[j][h] = 'p'

       if orientacion == 'V': # Orientacion vertical..
            anchura = corx+3
            altura= cory+longitud
            for j in range(cory,altura): #Limpio la posicion anterior.
               for h in range(corx,anchura):
                  t[j][h] = ' '
       if letramov <= ord('Z'): # Hacia arriba
            cory = cory+3
            cadena[2]=str(cory)
            altura = altura+3
       elif letramov >= ord('a'):# Hacia abajo
            cory = cory-3
            cadena[2] = str(cory)
            altura = altura-3

    for j in range(cory,altura): # Genero el coche
       for h in range(corx,anchura):
          t[j][h] = 'p'
```

Vale bien el problema es que yo traigo de un fichero externo una cadena tal que así "H113":

*( H ->Orientación en la matriz , horizontal H.// 1-> Coord x en matriz , 1->> coord y en matriz , 3 longitud del coche.. )*

La cual está almacenada en una sublista de otra lista .. Vale bien. El problema es que la finalidad de este algoritmo es mover un coche , y por tanto la posición del coche elemento [1] y [2] de la cadena x e y respectivamente deben actualizarse , y el string no me lo permite.. ¿Alguna solución se os ocurre? Desecho la posibilidad de modificar el fichero pues primero el fichero ya está abierto en modo lectura así como los niveles son rejugables y la modificación podría alterar el modo de juego.

Comment: Se puede dividir con `split` la cadena en sus componentes, modificar los necesarios y luego volverla a unir con `join`... es solo una idea.

Comment: Probaré , es lo que se me había ocurrido hace poco.. Cosillas de este lenguaje en el que me acabo de iniciar que poco a poco voy comprendiedo como la inmutabiidad.. Gracias por la respuesta.. probaré a ver si puedo eliminar la posición si no de la lista y añadirla.. Si lo consigo resolver , autoresuelvo el post.

Comment: No consigo crear una respuesta así que lo añado aquí . Vale bien , lo que hago es almacenar los valores iniciales debido a que estos van a ser multiplicados por tema de la matriz.. tras realizar las opraciones aquí viene mi solución bastante simple , así que lo siento por preguntar algo tan bobo eje . Creo una nueva cadena , con esos valores , elimino el actual ( Poyito es la variable que almacena el  índice ) y añado a esa posición la nueva cadena......  nuevacad = orientacion+str(x)+str(y)+str(l)  
    elemento.pop(poyito)
    elemento[poyito] = nuevacad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como las cadenas son inmutables, primero tendrías que convertirla en una lista.

```
>>> cad = 'hola'
>>> nva = list(cad)
```

Con esto puedes cambiar los elementos de la lista usando su índice:

```
>>> nva[0] = 'm'
```

Y luego unir la lista en la nueva cadena.

```
>>> cad = ''.join(nva)
>>> cad
'mola'
```

Seguro que se puede mejorar, pero esa es la idea.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda  :) Lo conseguí solucionar , en el caso de ser una cadena libre y no pertenecer a una lista sería como bien dices ! Muchas gracias.